# Ionic Native Facebook - Firebase Errors on Prod Build

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire, angularfire2, ionic-native

I'm working on an Ionic app with Facebook authentication using Firebase. I've tried many variations but I've narrowed it down to the problem being in the `@ionic-native/facebook` package.

***signin.ts***

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-signin',
    templateUrl: 'signin.html',
})
export class SigninPage {

    displayName;
    gas: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
                private toastCtrl: ToastController,
                private platform: Platform,
                private fb: Facebook,
                private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        afAuth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
            if (!user) {
                this.displayName = null;
                return;
            }
            this.displayName = user.displayName;      
        });
    }

    signInWithFacebook() {
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            return this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(res => {
                const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);

                const toast0 = this.toastCtrl.create({
                    message: 'Cordova return this.fb.login().then accessed',
                    duration: 3000
                });
                toast0.present();

                // return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
                return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
                    .then(res => {
                        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                            // message: JSON.stringify(res),
                            message: 'YAY',
                            duration: 3000
                        });
                        toast.present();
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        const toast2 = this.toastCtrl.create({
                            message: 'NAY',
                            duration: 3000
                        });
                        toast2.present();
                    });
            })
            .catch( err => {
                this.gas = err;
            });
        }
        else {
            return this.afAuth.auth
                .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
                .then(res => console.log(res));
        }
    }

    signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    }

}
```

I'm trying to print the random variable `gas` in the html via `<h2>{{ gas }}</h2>`. The `.then` does not seem to be accessed ever, so something must wrong with the

```
return this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
    .then()
    .catch();
```

Because it always goes into `.catch()`.

The *error* message printing off is just `[object Object]`. If I try to `this.gas = JSON.stringify(err);` I get `{}` returned. I'm not sure why the heck it's not giving me some basic error message. I don't know how to proceed to get this method working.

***EDIT:*** *Progress*

So I ran the app on an emulator, and was able to get an error message that made sense:

`{"errorMessage": "Facebook error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: 1349126, errorType: null, errorMessage: App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.}" }`

I've tried to put the app into production by adding `import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';` and `enableProdMode();` to my **`main.ts`** file. Now I get a plethora of new messages when I run `ionic cordova run android --prod`.

(and yes, I did run `npm install promise-polyfill --save --save-exact`)

```
Error: ./src/pages/signin/signin.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../angularfire2/auth' in 'C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\src\pages\signin'
resolve '../../../angularfire2/auth' in 'C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\src\pages\signin'
using description file: C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/signin)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
after using description file: C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/signin)
    using description file: C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\package.json (relative path: ./angularfire2/auth)
    no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth doesn't exist
    .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth.js doesn't exist
    .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth.ts doesn't exist
    as directory
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth doesn't exist
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth]
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth.js]
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth.ts]
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth]
@ ./src/pages/signin/signin.ngfactory.js 33:0-55
@ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
@ ./src/app/main.ts,./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../angularfire2/auth' in 'C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\src\app'
resolve '../../angularfire2/auth' in 'C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\src\app'
using description file: C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
after using description file: C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    using description file: C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\package.json (relative path: ./angularfire2/auth)
    no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth doesn't exist
    .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth.js doesn't exist
    .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth.ts doesn't exist
    as directory
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth doesn't exist
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth]
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth.js]
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth.ts]
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\auth]
@ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 32:0-52
@ ./src/app/main.ts,./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../angularfire2/database' in 'C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\src\app'
resolve '../../angularfire2/database' in 'C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\src\app'
using description file: C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
after using description file: C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    using description file: C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\package.json (relative path: ./angularfire2/database)
    no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\database doesn't exist
    .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\database.js doesn't exist
2\database.js doesn't exist
    .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration  2\database.ts doesn't exist
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire
2\database.ts doesn't exist                                          2\database doesn't exist
    as directory
        C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\database doesn't exist
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\database]
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\database.js]
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\database.ts]
[C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\t\ionic-project\movie-list\angularfire2\database]
@ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 31:0-56
@ ./src/app/main.ts
```

Version:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Kenny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Node : v7.9.0
    npm  : 5.3.0
    OS   : Windows 10
```

Comment: If you try in the HTML `{{ gas | json }}` what do you get back?

Comment: I get `"{}"`. I've looked around the docs, and they just say throws an error, so I'm not sure why it's not saying anything.

Comment: You've got a facebook app created and registered in your `config.xml`?

Comment: Yes, I do. And it works on desktop. It's just natively on the phone, it doesn't seem to work. I see Facebook popup on the phone briefly, then go away. It's like it attempts the `this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])` and then fails and goes straight to `.catch()`.